# How to change header of content panel gxt

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am struggling to make an header of content panel look like blinking by changing the color of it. But the code I am trying does not work, here the code:

```
public class Reminder extends ContentPanel{
Timer time = new Timer{
public void run(){
rpc.getReminders(new AsyncCallBack<ArrayList<ModelData>>(){
public voidonFailure(Throwable caught)
{ }
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<ModelData> result){
//the next line does not affect any result
getHeader().setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","red");
//even tried throught css, but both of them gave no result
getHeader().addStyleName("myredpanel");
//But this method is working, but its also overwriting the parents css styles, but i only need to change backgroun color
getHeader().setStyleName("myredpanel");
})
```

Searched the forums, but those examples doesnot working on mine? What else suggestions?

Comment: Setting/Adding styles can be tricky. Have you looked at the style names in your compiled application? Are you using internal or external stylesheets? Are you able to make/observe the style change within firebug?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the camel case names when you call `setStyleAttribute`.

```
getHeader().setStyleAttribute("backgroundColor","red"); // WRONG

getHeader().setStyleAttribute("background-color","red"); // CORRECT
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gxt 3.0.X you should change ContentPanelAppereance, direct style setting may not be helpfull. if you want, i can send an example.

Comment: You need to write your example to make you answer relevant.